# Ordering slash separated list

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I have column 'GUI_KVLevelName'.
It has data as :

500.00/69.00/34.50 
500.00/400.00/138.00 
500.00/69.00 
500.00/400.00 
500.00/345.00/34.50 
57.00/8.30

I want to use order by with this. It is a varchar column but i want to order it as numeric.  So how could i use order by this column?

Comment: well what would the order be for you? You can use `order by` like your normally would and it'll sort it, but maybe in a unwanted way. You also need to give some info about this column like how many slashes or groups can be there, cause splitting it could be the best

Comment: @scsimon if i use order by normaly,  it is showing ordering same as varchar.  Means 82 come first then 811 so on in ascending order.

Comment: @scsimon slashes are vary.. It is not fixed.  May be 2 or 3 or none

Comment: Ok, so you want it ordered as if they were numeric.... but you have some pairs mixed with tuples... so how would you handle those? I'd handle this in the application level

Comment: @scsimon yes damn right,  i want to order it as numeric. Is it possible to handle in sql server?

Comment: By far the best solution would be to stop storing multiple values in a single tuple like this. You are struggling here because your architecture violates 1NF. To do this with the data in it's present format would mean you have to parse those values into columns (possibly dynamic unless you know how many there might be), then order by those columns. No solution to this is going to be anything less than horrific.

Comment: @SeanLange slashes are vary,  so dont know how many dynamic columns need to make.  So this approach will not work

Comment: Which further backs up the idea that proper normalization would be the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second answer in case you can't GTD two decimal places.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([GUI_KVLevelName] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('500.00/69.00/34.50')
,('500.00/400.00/138.00')
,('500.00/69.00')
,('500.00/400.00')
,('500.00/345.00/34.50')
,('0.45/5.30')
,('0.1/9.30')
,('0.01/9.30')
,('0.05/9.30')
,('1.3/4.30')

Select A.*
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','money')
                      ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','money')
                      ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','money')
                      ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','money')
                      ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','money')
                      ,Pos6 = xDim.value('/x[6]','money')
                      ,Pos7 = xDim.value('/x[7]','money')
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace([GUI_KVLevelName],'/','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
 Order By Pos1,Pos2,Pos3,Pos4,Pos5,Pos6,Pos7
```

**Returns**

```
GUI_KVLevelName
0.01/9.30
0.05/9.30
0.1/9.30
0.45/5.30
1.3/4.30
500.00/69.00
500.00/69.00/34.50
500.00/345.00/34.50
500.00/400.00
500.00/400.00/138.00
```

Comment: Awesome!  Working with zeroes as well.  I am understanding how you did it with xml.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little cheat that may work

By removing the decimal points, we are converting the individual values into a larger INT.   This is then converted to and then sorted via a `hierarchyid` type

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([GUI_KVLevelName] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('500.00/69.00/34.50')
,('500.00/400.00/138.00')
,('500.00/69.00')
,('500.00/400.00')
,('500.00/345.00/34.50')
,('0.45/5.30')          -- Added for leading zero
,('0.10/9.30')          -- Added for leading zero

Select *
 From @YourTable
 Order By try_convert(hierarchyid,replace('/'+replace([GUI_KVLevelName],'.','1')+'/','/0','/'))
```

**Returns**

```
GUI_KVLevelName
0.10/9.30
0.45/5.30
500.00/69.00
500.00/69.00/34.50
500.00/345.00/34.50
500.00/400.00
500.00/400.00/138.00
```

Comment: Hey it works!  One more thing.  Whenever it  encounters  value starts with 0, it is not showing correct answer. Add value 0.45 after slash at the end and try again.  Any solution?

Comment: @shikhil Looking into it now.  The hierarchyid expects /int/int/  testing a quick fix now

Comment: @shikhil See updated answer.  I just added one more replace  ...  /0  with /  This will eliminate the leading zero

Comment: @shikhil would you have any values 0.0#   If so, we may have to wrap it in a second replace(...,'/0','/')

Comment: I dont have 0.0 value. Now only it is not working fine when  there value 1 or something like 1.3 means between 1 and 2

Comment: @shikhil OK the hierarchyid may not be a good fit for this then.   There is another alternative.  Is there a max number of nodes?

Comment: Sorry.  Its working fine in my case now.  I was trying with 1. But i have 1.00 or like 1.24  so it is working fine here.. Thanks a lot for the help and time

Comment: @shikhil Great.  Just keep in mind that we are expecting two decimals.   1.30 will become 130 but 1.3 will become 13    I'll post the alternative just in case you can't gtd two decimals

Comment: @shikhil Added a second answer just in case  :)